# Не происходит правильно вычисление сигмы

Tags: c++

Хай.
Ребят, кто знает, почему мой код не работает правильно? Вроде бы всё правильно, но сумма - 19. А это неправильный ответ. Решение должно быть именно с использованием оператора do/while...
Что тут не так?

```
double i1 = 1;
double summ = 0;
do {
    summ += (1/i1 + 18*i1);
    i1--;
} while (i1 > 16);
cout << "Результат вычисления сигмы =: " << summ << endl;
```

Условие задачи:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Так а что это у вас за цикл такой, который сразу завершает работу? Что это за условие `i1 > 16`, когда `i1` сначала 1, а потом становится 0? Что вы хотели сказать этим условием? Да и условие задачи какое-то странное. Что там делает это `i-1` внизу?

Comment: Всё, Вы решили мою проблему, спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

Ошибка была в этих строках:

```
   i1++;
} while (i1 < 16);
```

Comment: Вы бы удалили вопрос - другим он вряд ли поможет...